# Dynamically listen to custom event on parent component

Tags: vue.js

In my custom library I have several components which run ajax requests, and when a given request fails the component emits an `error` event.

Then, in my main component I want to listen to all `error` events emmited and run the method `handleErrors`, but for that I have to go on every component and add `@error="handleErrors"`.

Is there a way to configure my main component to catch `error` events dynamically and call `handleErrors` without going on each component and adding it? Preferrably changes to the main component only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured a way to do it without refactoring the individual components: just injected the listener in every component using a mixin.

The result:

```
// Before starting up the main instance:
Vue.mixin({
    created: function() {
        this.$on('error', function(error) {
            // Then I handled the errors here.
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the EventBus system in Vue instance. Actually EventBus is a different Vue instance your Main Vue instance. You make your own Event bus system.`$emit`, `$on` and `$off` events.

***event-bus.js***

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

and now you are ready to use.

***some-component.vue***

```vue
// Import the EventBus.
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';
// Send the event on a channel (eventName) with a payload (the click count.)
EventBus.$emit('eventName', this.clickCount);
```

***other-component.vue***

```vue
// Import the EventBus.
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';

// Listen for the eventName event and its payload.
EventBus.$on('eventName', clickCount => {
  console.log(clickCount)
});

// Stop listening.
EventBus.$off('eventName');
```

more information and example
https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/

Comment: Editing the components is undesirable (as there are plenty of them) but if no better approach comes up I'll do it